# convert dictionary into xls file using python openpyxl library

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, dictionary, openpyxl

Below is my dictionary & I want to write the key-value pair of dictionary into excel sheet in two columns named `key` & `hourly`.

```
'One year reserved'= {
        'Australia Central 2': 0.0097,
        'East US 2': 0.00605,
        'North Central US': 0.00605,
        'South Africa West': 0.01016,
        'UK West': 0.00685,
        'France South': 0.01119,
        'Korea': 0.00639,
        'Canada East': 0.00685,
        'US Gov Virginia': 0.00879,
        'East Asia': 0.0097,
        'South India': 0.01005,
        'South Central US': 0.00731,
        'West US': 0.00719,
        'Australia East': 0.00776,
        'Canada Central': 0.00674,
        'Australia Southeast': 0.00776,
        'Southeast Asia': 0.00776,
        'Central US': 0.00731,
        'West India': 0.00833,
        'East US': 0.00605,
        'Australia Central': 0.0097,
        'UK South': 0.00685,
        'Japan East': 0.00799,
        'Japan West': 0.00879,
        'West Europe': 0.00696,
        'Brazil South': 0.00982,
        'Korea Central': 0.00799,
        'US Gov Texas': 0.00879,
        'US Gov Arizona': 0.00879,
        'Central India': 0.00833,
        'North Europe': 0.00822,
        'West Central US': 0.00731,
        'France Central': 0.00856,
        'South Africa North': 0.00811,
        'West US 2': 0.00605
      }
```

convert dictionary into xls file using python openpyxl library.
output should be like this:-

```
**Key**                   **Hourly**
Australia Central 2        0.008
East US 2                  0.00605
North Central US           0.00605
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample output in proper format, what should be the column names, no of columns etc.

Comment: thanks for your comment but I have solved my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
one_year_reserved = {
        'australia-central': 0.0097,
        'usgov-virginia': 0.00879,
        'us-south-central': 0.00731,
        'france-south': 0.01119,
        'us-west': 0.00719,
        'europe-north': 0.00822,
        'asia-pacific-east': 0.0097,
        'japan-east': 0.00799,
        'west-india': 0.00833,
        'united-kingdom-west': 0.00685,
        'usgov-arizona': 0.00879,
        'brazil-south': 0.00982,
        'australia-east': 0.00776,
        'us-west-2': 0.00605,
        'asia-pacific-southeast': 0.00776,
        'south-india': 0.01005,
        'us-central': 0.00731,
        'us-east-2': 0.00605,
        'south-africa-west': 0.01016,
        'canada-central': 0.00674,
        'south-africa-north': 0.00811,
        'canada-east': 0.00685,
        'us-east': 0.00605,
        'korea-south': 0.00639,
        'united-kingdom-south': 0.00685,
        'europe-west': 0.00696,
        'japan-west': 0.00879,
        'australia-southeast': 0.00776,
        'us-west-central': 0.00731,
        'us-north-central': 0.00605,
        'central-india': 0.00833,
        'korea-central': 0.00799,
        'usgov-texas': 0.00879,
        'france-central': 0.00856,
        'australia-central-2': 0.0097
    }


with open('output2.csv', 'wb') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for key, value in one_year_reserved.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution working with python 3.6+ because it uses f-strings. `enumerate` is used not to have to store the row number in another reference.

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook

data = {
    'australia-central': 0.0097,
    'usgov-virginia': 0.00879,
}

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

sheet["A1"] = "Key"
sheet["B1"] = "Hourly"

for row, (key, hourly) in enumerate(data.items(), start=2):
    sheet [f"A{row}"] = key
    sheet [f"B{row}"] = hourly

workbook.save("output.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . It works fine !

```
# Writing to an excel 
# sheet using Python 
import xlwt 
from xlwt import Workbook 

# Workbook is created 
wb = Workbook() 

#dictionary
sample_data= {
    'Australia Central 2': 0.0097,
    'East US 2': 0.00605,
    'North Central US': 0.00605,
    'South Africa West': 0.01016,
    'UK West': 0.00685,
    'France South': 0.01119,
    'Korea': 0.00639,
    'Canada East': 0.00685,
    'US Gov Virginia': 0.00879,
    'East Asia': 0.0097,
    'South India': 0.01005,
    'South Central US': 0.00731,
    'West US': 0.00719,
    'Australia East': 0.00776,
    'Canada Central': 0.00674,
    'Australia Southeast': 0.00776,
    'Southeast Asia': 0.00776,
    'Central US': 0.00731,
    'West India': 0.00833,
    'East US': 0.00605,
    'Australia Central': 0.0097,
    'UK South': 0.00685,
    'Japan East': 0.00799,
    'Japan West': 0.00879,
    'West Europe': 0.00696,
    'Brazil South': 0.00982,
    'Korea Central': 0.00799,
    'US Gov Texas': 0.00879,
    'US Gov Arizona': 0.00879,
    'Central India': 0.00833,
    'North Europe': 0.00822,
    'West Central US': 0.00731,
    'France Central': 0.00856,
    'South Africa North': 0.00811,
    'West US 2': 0.00605
  }

# add_sheet is used to create sheet. 
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1') 

#general syntax
#sheet1.write(column, row, value) 

sheet1.write(0, 0, 'Key') 
sheet1.write(1, 0, 'Hourly') 

row = 1
#iterate the each key-value pair of dictionary & insert into sheet
for k, v in dict.items():
    sheet1.write(0, row, k) 
    sheet1.write(1, row, v) 
    row = row + 1

wb.save('xlwt example.xls')
```